# Checking for duplicates in an array, while ignoring zeros (Python)

Tags: python, set, duplicates

I am trying to find duplicates in an array but I want to ignore duplicate zeros.

This is my code so far, if anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong that would be great.

The array has no duplicates in it in this question but when I run it with and without duplicates it always returns 'Error'

```
import sys
mat =[[0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,3],[0,1,0,0,9,2,6,0,0],[0,0,0,0,2,4,0,8,0],  [0,0,7,0,0,0,0,6,0],[4,0,0,8,1,0,7,0,0],[0,0,1,4,0,7,0,5,6],[0,0,5,0,8,0,0,9,4],[0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0]]
def check_duplicate():
    global mat
    for row in mat:
        for num in row:
            if (num != 0):
                ls = [num]
                sort = sorted(ls)
                if (sort != set(sort)):
                    sys.exit('Error')
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: If there are duplicates of any numbers but 0 I want the program to stop. If there are no duplicates the program continues (sudoku solver)

Comment: `sort` is a list, and `set(sort)` is a set. They'll never be equal. Also, `sort` and `set(sort)` are both just going to have the single element `num` in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do this...simply append all numbers that are not 0 into a check list and if you would append the same number twice, raise an error:

```
#mat is your matrix
for row in mat:
    hold = []
    for num in row:
        if num in hold:
            raise ValueError("There was an illegal repetition")
        elif num != 0:
            hold.append(num)
```

Essentially what this does is put all numbers that are not 0 inside the list `hold`. But before it puts the number it checks to see if the number is already in `hold`, and if it is, it raises a `ValueError`. Then the list is reset to blank at every row of your matrix and it repeats.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to raise `SyntaxError` yourself. Something like `ValueError` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @WaleedKhan good point. I simply chose `SyntaxError` because I use it more often and was not sure of all the other error names, but yes, `ValueError` is more appropriate here. edited.

Comment: Turns out I just accidentally forgot to indent something. Thank you very much for this, it works great!

Answer (score 0):

sorted(...) return a sorted list, can't be equal to a set

1.def a func to filter out zeros in a row

```
func = lambda l : [num for num in l if num != 0]
```

2.check duplicate in each row

```
for row in map(func, mat):
    if len(row) != len(set(row)):
        #error message
```

3.to check duplicate in multiple rows, answer of @aIKid works fine, thanks for rectify

Comment: Hm, this isn't an answer. Wait until you have 50 reps then comment, or post a proper answer..

Comment: Still, the problem is not with the length :) It needs to know if there is multiple values.

Comment: multiple values in different rows? ok, a mistake

Answer (score 0):

I'd strip all the zeroes first, then check if the sets are already in an existing list:

```
def check(l):
    l = [[j for j in i if j != 0] for i in l]
    new = []
    #after throwing all the zeroes:
    for row in l:
        if set(row) in new:
            raise ValueError("There are multiple items")
        else:
            new.append(set(row))
```

Hope this helps!